What are the requirement for a custom new operator in C++?
I am trying to understand what are the real requirements for a custom overloaded new operator in C++.
Especially concerning the alignment of the returned pointer, in the case where the operator new is called without any alignment specification.
void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
}

I have seen this preprocessor value __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__. However, it is not clear if this is the minimal alignment value for all memory.
There is also a passage of the standard that says that "Allocation functions" should return pointer such that:

... the storage is aligned for any object that does not have new-extended alignment and is of the requested size.

So my question is two-fold:

What is the minimum alignment for a given size for this new operator?
If the returned pointer's alignment is less than that, What is the consequence? Is it UB?

Edit :
I want to clarify the reason for my question. (I was trying to keep it generic, but I see that it made me miss the point.)
My example is this one: Godbolt of example
I call new on an object with no alignment specifier, that I want zero-initialized.
The compiler here assumes that the zero-initialized pointer is 16 bytes aligned: movaps copies register in a 16-byte aligned memory location.
But if I had a custom new operator (Hard to repro in a Godbolt) which returned a 8-byte aligned pointer, the call to movaps could crash.
So there must be a hard requirement somewhere.

AFAIK there arent many. Just that it returns a pointer into memory that can hold data of std::size_t. You can make it as badly performant as you want and it is still valid.  For example debug builds sometimes have an new operator that actually allocates guard bytes before and after the object and fill those bytes with patterns (to detect out of bound access). My question back is why do you want to know?

Can you not use alignof? If the memory is not correctly aligned, then you are breaking the specifications of the language. What happens when don't adhere to the language specifications (the compiler can do anything). I believe but can no longer quote that alignments are all powers of 2 up to the max alignment alignof(std::max_align_t).

@martin-york I would like to avoid alignof, in my original case, the actual struct was from a third party library.

C++ has to support a multitude of  architectures hence the alignment requirement.
Imagine what would happen if you align on 8 bytes on a 16 bit architecture (with memory pages) and the last byte of the type would end up in a different page.
Now it will become too hard too manage at runtime. Also a CPU's usually don't have unaligned memory access. Or to get to a value inside your type it would need to load from two addresses. So yes aliginment is an important part (as well as being aware of page boundaries)

cppreferences states:

This function is required to return a pointer suitably aligned to point to an object of the requested size.

This pretty much rephrases the standard quote you used.
Basically, you need to know the platform. Usually, alignments are needed/useful for the "basic" items, like pointers, integers or doubles; more complex objects like structs usually have no aligment requirements by themselves, but need the members aligned suitably. Which means the compiler has to assume a suitable alignment for the struct, so it can arrange the members, which is usually the alignment for anything that could be in the struct.
The quote basically says that if you have a request for 4 bytes, you'll have to align it so any 4 byte object is happy -- like integers or floats. If it's an 8-byte object, you'll have to make sure it works for pointers and doubles. If you have a 16-byte object, and your platform doesn't have any 16-byte primitives, it's definitely a structure and you'll want to align it to least the requirements for the aforementioned 8-byte objects -- unless your compiler says otherwise and prefers 16-byte alignments for whatever reason. Of course, all these numbers are just examples. Your platform and compiler may differ.

As for "what happens if it's misaligned" -- treat it as undefined behavior. Depending on the compiler, it can seriously mess up its structure padding even to the extent that it puts data before the block you've returned; depending on the CPU, a misaligned data item can cause a crash in the worst case, or serious performance degradation in a better case (although, personally, I see the crash as the good case because it tells me something is wrong...).

Note: There is also a max alignment alignof(std::max_align_t) you don't need alignment past that.

In reverse order

If the returned pointer's alignment is less than that, What is the
consequence? Is it UB?

This depends entirely on the processor (using C-style cast)
double *a = (double *) (((char *) new double[2]) + 1)
*a = 10.0 * *a ;

On some processors (especially RISC) you will get an exception. On other processors you will just get a performance hit because the processor has to do multiple reads from memory and write to memory.

What is the minimum alignment for a given size for this new operator?

That will depend upon the implementation. If your processor has 128-bit floating point values, the memory allocator implementer is going to have a minimum alignment of 16 bits.
Note that most such allocators prepend data to the memory block returned. That data will typically include some pointers. An allocator needs to align the block for its own purposes which usually means the returned data is aligned as well.
 void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
 {
    BlockDescriptor *mem = allocateFromOperatingSystem (sz + sizeof (*mem)) ;
     mem->whatever = somethingToKeepTrackOfMemoryBlock ;
     return (void*) &mem [1] ;
 }

